# TypeScript: make a method of a generic interface A<T> available only if T is of a certain type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Please look at this code:

```
interface A<T> {
    method1(): A<T>;
}

interface B<T extends Function> extends A<T> {
    method2(): B<T>;
}

var foo: A<Function>;
foo.method1();
foo.method2();
```

I expected `foo` to be compatible with the `B<Function>` type, but instead I get `error TS2339: Property 'method2' does not exist on type 'A<Function>'`. Can I rewrite the interface `B` somehow to get it to work?

Actually, I'm trying to fix the typings for lodash's `_.memoize`:

```
// This should be OK. The type of result1 should be compatible with aFunction.
var result1 = _(aFunction).memoize().value();

// And this should be an error.
var result2 = _(aNonFunctionValue).memoize().value();
```

**UPDATE.** Basically, my question is: can I write such a generic method for `A<T>` that it'll be available only if `T` is a subtype of some other type `U`?

Comment: Is there a good reason why you are using the chain syntax for Lodash instead of just doing `_.memoize(aFunction)`?

Comment: No. I just was fixing other issues with the typings for `memoize` and noticed this one.

Comment: Does the problem happen when you use the non-chain syntax?

Comment: No. This issue is specifically about the chain syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Turns out TypeScript doesn't support this. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1290</s>

**UPDATE 2019:** Now that we have [Conditional Types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types), it's a piece of cake:

```
interface A<T> {
    method1(): A<T>;
    method2: T extends Function ? () => A<T> : never;
}

declare var foo: A<Function>;
foo.method1();
foo.method2();
```

Answer (score 3):

> Can I rewrite the interface B somehow to get it to work?

## Solution

Here is the code:

```
interface A<T> {
    method1(): A<T>;
}

interface B<T extends Function> extends A<T> {
    method2(): B<T>;
}

interface A<T> {
    method2<T extends Function>(): B<T>;
}

var foo: A<Function>;
foo.method1();
foo.method2(); // works!
```

## Arriving at the solution

Lets take a step back and think what we *want to work*:

```
var foo: A<Function>;
foo.method2(); // Should work
```

This means that `A<Function>` should have `method2` on it. So:

```
interface A<T> {
    method2<T extends Function>(): B<T>;
}
```

And this method two adds a generic contraint on `T` and returns something of type `B`.

The rest is clear in the final solution

Comment: No, it doesn't really do what is needed. Replace the type in `var foo: A<Function>;` with some subtype of `Function`, e.g. `()=>void`, and you'll see that `foo.method2()` still returns `B<Function>`, not `B<()=>void>`.

Comment: At least now I see why it doesn't work this way. Since the type system is structural, `foo` has to match structurally to `B<T>`, which is not the case. So basically my question is: **can I write such a generic method for `A<T>` that it'll be available only if `T` is a subtype of some other type `U`**?

Comment: `can I write such a generic method for A<T> that it'll be available only if T is a subtype of some other type U` No.

Comment: Consider having any T in A to extend Function. i.e. put the constraint on A

Comment: I can't do this. `A<T>` is universal. It can be used for any types. But some of its methods make sense only if `T` is `Function`.

Comment: See [this line](https://github.com/thorn0/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b5817cd2f8eb6714e4e69f190698ca7c1bc5bea5/lodash/lodash.d.ts#L9572). It's easy to make `_.memoise(fn)` compile only if `fn` is a function, but what about `_(fn).memoize()`? Seems like it's really impossible to enforce the type-checking for `fn` here. Unless I'm missing some feature of TypeScript's type system. Hence my question.

Comment: Declaring types Lodash chaining in such a way is really hard, I don't think it's currently possible tbh.  I've run into a similar problem with RxJS, there is no good way to say "this method only exists under this constraint" without declaring and returning a different interface (which is sometimes hard).  It might be possible to do `declare function _<T extends Fucntion>(value: Function): FunctionChainable;` as an additional  overload, but I don't know.